# Convert PDF to image use CI and the path is not correct

Tags: codeigniter, imagemagick

```
function Upload_file(){
   $config = array(
        'image_library' => 'ImageMagick',
        'library_path' => '/usr/bin/convert',
        'source_image' => './files/test/images.pdf',
        'new_image' => './files/test/a.jpg',
        'maintain_ratio' => true,
        'quality' => '100%',
  );
   $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
   if ( !$this->image_lib->resize()){
      echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
   } 
   $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

Hi i'm trying to convert pdf file to jpg but the controller it replies a message
"imglib_invalid_image.
 imglib_image_process_failed"
Could any one help me how to execute this code .

Comment: You are trying to process a pdf not image.

Comment: so this is because CI image_lib doesn't support PDF ? Do i have other solutions?